# How can I call different controllers from routes.rb

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, routes

I'm just struggling a few hours with a problem, that seems rather easy, but not for me and not for google :)

I put some routes via

```
scope :path => '/:mandate_key', :controller => :tasks do
  get   '/'          =>  :index        #mandate_path
  match '/import'    => "import#index"
  match '/clearance' => "clearance#index"
end
```

So far, so ugly! I'm looking for a way to call different controllers (import and clearance) dependent on the second param. Something like this:

```
scope :path => '/:mandate_key', :controller => :tasks do
  get '/' =>  :index  
  scope :path => ':task_key', :controller => %{'task_key'}
    get '/' => :index
  end
end
```

where `:task_key` should be recognized as `params[:task_key]` and the called controller should be the value of `params[:task_key]`

So if a click a link like `http://some.url/a_mandate_key/import` it should call the `ImportController`.

I'm sure that the solution will be simple, but finding is hard!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sometimes one is looking for a highly complicated solution, but it could be so much easier:

```
scope :path => '/:mandate_key' do
  get '/'           => "tasks#index"        #mandate_path
  get '/import'     => "import#index"
  get '/clearance'  => "clearance#index"
end
```

Calling http://localhost/mandate the controller 'mandate' is called an params[:mandate_key] provides 'mandate'

Calling http://localhost/mandate/import the controller 'import' is called an params[:controller] provides 'import'

Trying the easy way is often the best way :)

Thanks for your help, Bohdan!

Answer (score 1):

you might add in the bottom of your routes `match ':controller(/:action(/:id))'` so any unknown url will be dispatched this way

How about

```
scope :path => '/:mandate_key', :controller => :tasks do
  get '/'            =>  :index        #mandate_path
end
....
match ':mandate_key/:controller(/:action)'
```

first scope will match routes `/:mandate_key/tasks` and the second one `/:mandate_key/:controller` or `/:mandate_key/:controller/:action` however second part should be defined in the bottom of your `routes.rb` file otherwise it'll match wrong routes

Comment: sure, but this way I can't get the task_key via params[:task_key]

Comment: To express it more clearly: afte the login a get the base URL http://localhost:3000  When I choosed a mandate, I get http://localhost:3000/a_mandate/  Depending on my login and the mandate I'll get several tasks, choosing one of them will provide me http://localhost:3000/a_mandate/a_task  

Using my scope in the above code, I can get the mandate's name via params[:mandate_key]. Now I need the same for the task via params[:task_key] and calling the last URL should call the controller for the task

Comment: I've checked your solution and it doesn't provide what I'm looking for. So here are the examples:

http://localhost:3000/first_mandate  - should call controller 'tasks' (works through scope in line 1 in code above)

http://localhost/first_mandate/import - should call controller 'import'

http://localhost/first_mandate/clearance - should call controller 'clearance'

http://localhost/first_mandate/import/first_action - should call method 'first_action' in controller 'import'

http://localhost/first_mandate/clearance/another_action - should call method 'another_action' in controller 'clearance'

Comment: nope, sorry: No route matches "/mandate/import" 
If you take a look at my very first code in routes.rb above with the match inside the scope: This one is working and provides me the controller call I expect. But this way it's not possible to get the value of the 2nd parameter in the URL.

http://localhost/mandate/import => params[:mandate_key] is providing 'mandate' (as expected). Now I need way to call controller 'import' AND get the value 'import' through params[:task_key]

Maybe there are a few losses of sense during my translation to english

Comment: forgot parentheses indeed devil is in the details